# Run configuration start external program in rider

Tags: .net, macos, external, rider, run-configuration

I am new to using Rider. Currently, I am working with **JetBrains Rider 2020.3.2** (osx).
Until recently I was using Visual Studio for Mac and there I had the possibility as run configuration to have for example the following setup (see image):

[Project options with Run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Acn.png)

This allowed me to start an external program in order to debug the solution.

Now as I transferred to Rider I cannot seem to find a way that allows me to start an external program. Is there already a setup for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Main menu `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` would show UI for adding.
There are separate templates for `.NET Executable` and `Native Executable`.

I have worked with 2 types of native apps, which host embedded mono. Both have debugging support in Rider improved via plugin. [Unity](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/blob/net211/rider/src/main/kotlin/com/jetbrains/rider/plugins/unity/run/configurations/unityExe/UnityExeDebugProfileState.kt#L48). [Godot](https://github.com/JetBrains/godot-support/blob/net203/rider/src/main/kotlin/com/jetbrains/rider/plugins/godot/run/configurations/GodotDebugProfileState.kt#L43).

Maybe the approach can be generalized, requested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-42273).

Out-of-the-box debugging of embedded mono is not so straitforward, you would need separate Launch and Attach configurations as shown [here](https://github.com/van800/cryengine_example/tree/master/DebugFromRider/.idea/.idea.Game/.idea/runConfigurations)

Comment: and is there the possibility with the Native Executable to allow debugging? For example to setup a configuration with NativeExecutable and when you start it to start it with debugging in rider?

Comment: Forgot to mention I am talking about running a MacOs app and running a .Net Project and i want to achieve debugging in the .Net Project.

Comment: Is it native app with embedded mono?

Comment: We are talking about a native macos app. The app is the UI for the .Net part. I can run the App from Xcode, but from there I cannot achieve the debugging in .Net. 
Previously I was doing this with Visual Studio for mac. But since i now have Rider, I wanted to achieve it there as well. So running the macos app as native executable and debugging into the .Net part in Rider.

Comment: Are we talking about Xamarin? How that C# container is embedded?

Comment: We are talking about a pure native macOS UI App. The project in XCode contains the dlls from the C# Project. And then as mentioned in my question for example I can achieve that under Visual Studio for mac just by running in the Configurations an External program (which is the .app program that is build from XCode) and as Run in directory path i setup the path to the c# dlls which are contained as contents under the macos app

Comment: Have you created the application from some template in VSfM or XCode? Which template was it? I have just installed VSfM to check, but Cocoa App, which I checked, just works (run/debug) in Rider.

Comment: The application in VSfM is a netcoreapp2.1 with outputType exe. And for XCode it is a new App applicaiton for macOS

Comment: Any tutorial or step-by-step guide on how native app loads the netcore app?

Comment: example project may help